# How to change the default homescreen

Tags: android, android-intent, homescreen

I created a homescreen application and made it the default homescreen, but how can I call the chooser to make the old one default again from the app? I´m gessing some Intent..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

goto your application AndroidManifest.xml file and -
Application tab -> select your activity -> goto right side Name* -> browse -> wait for a while to loading activity list -> select your activity which you want to keep as default activity -> remove the activity if it is already previously added into application list.

Comment: Is there a way, that I create a button that goes to the default homescreen chooser? So on the device itself?

Comment: default home screen chooses means, you want to talking about multiple activity from one to switch another?